# Can you tell if the image is sharp or blurry if the picture is clicked from a mobile phone?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Given a mobile phone with known picture resolution and focal length, is it possible to determine whether a single image clicked through the phone camera is blurry or not?

Answer (score 0):

Whether an image is blurry or not can often be a very subjective decision. There are approaches utilizing laplacian variance to identify blurry pictures, but this has a few shortcomings as well.

Related : [Blur detection with OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/)

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that approach and I was wondering if something better can be done when the focal length of the camera is known.

Comment: Well, do you know a relation between focal length and overall blur? I know that there can be a relation between focal length and *background blur*, but not explicitly *overall blur*. If not, the additional information about the focal length doesn't really benefit you.

Here's an article that might help you: [Focal length and background blur](https://lewiscollard.com/technical/background-blur/)